# MongoDB replication issue with 2 nodes

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have configured my mongo DB replica set with 2 nodes (our use case is not fail over case), So we have one primary and one non-voting secondary, and no arbiter. The idea is to have normal application traffic to go to the primary and some analytics-related queries go to the secondary and also some external data analytics team to use the secondary node for read-only purposes.

I have set the default global read and write concern in the following way.

```
db.adminCommand({
  "setDefaultRWConcern" : 1,
  "defaultWriteConcern" : {
    "w" : 2
  },
  "defaultReadConcern" : { "level" : "majority" }
})
```

And my connection details as follows :

```
await mongoose.connect(dbUrl,{replicaSet: 'replname', readPreference : 'primary'});
```

Here comes my issue :

on creating user like following in node JS code

```
await User.create({ name: 'test-user'});
```

and reading it immediately :

```
await User.findOne({name:'test-user'})
```

it gives NULL result.

here we have 2 issues ==>

1. My assumption is, as we have mentioned ‘primary’ as the default readPreference in connection URL, the query should fetch results always from the primary., looks like it’s trying to fetch from the secondary.
2. as we have set writeConcern as ==> w:2, where it indicates response will be returned on 2 of the nodes are completed their replication. So even from secondary latest data should come instead of returning NULL.

we are working with mongo DB 6.0.0 on ubuntu(20.04.4 LTS) VM.

please let me know if am missing anything here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With following read and write concerns,

```
db.adminCommand({
  "setDefaultRWConcern" : 1,
  "defaultWriteConcern" : {
    "w" : 2
  },
  "defaultReadConcern" : { "level" : "majority" }
})
```

And knowing little more on readConcerns, we come to conclusion that why I faced these issues. I just mentioned them below with their cause.

Issue 1 :
As I have mentioned my writeConcern as ==> {w:2} data might not have been durable by the time am reading it through readConcern of ==> “majority”,
May be because of that I was not getting data even from primary node

Issue 2 :
Same thing applies to Secondary as well, with writeConcern as ==> {w:2} and read concern as ==>. “majority” you are trying to read durable data from secondary.
By the time that you are trying to read, it might not have been durable in the secondary.

With this , readConcern also plays a major role while reading the data. In our case, as we are not using any Transaction for storing data, and speed is main concern,
{readConcern: ‘local’} makes more sense for us. With this we get data faster as we are not looking at any fail over cases.

Hope this helps.

more info here ==> https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-replication-issues/240115/6